# Bootstrap Dropdown With Background Dim

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple navbar in Bootstrap 3, with a drop down.

I'm looking to dim the background while the drop down is open (similar to when a modal is open). I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: You'd have a better chance of getting good answers if you post (only) the relevant parts of your HTML / CSS. Even though you don't have any errors (yet), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) has some useful info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar resource that describes it better than I could. It is basically a modal dialog box in the example. But the important part for you is the jquery as it is dependant on where the class of the click event is placed which you would place in the html tag for your dropdown. I hope this helps. http://www.webdesignfact.com/2011/06/quick-way-to-dim-and-cover-background-content-with-jquery.html

Comment: Thanks, this should help a lot! I think I can get the code I need from here. Thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: Awesome Johnathan Doe! I'm glad I could help. Feel free to check my answer as accepted.